# Save google maps location to google account only allowing 1 query

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to allow users to save their markers lat and lng to their google account. It works fine for the first marker, but then stops working for subsequent markers.

For example load the fiddle bellow then 
1. click the left marker (saving is allowed)
2. click the marker on the right (saving is NOT allowed)
3. reload the fiddle(refresh the page)
4. this time click the RIGHT marker (saving is allowed)
5. click the marker on the left (saving is NOT allowed)

https://jsfiddle.net/74zfffj3/

How to I allow all markers to be saved to user google account, and not just the first marker clicked?

Answer (score 1):

I can enable save on multiple markers/infowindows if I provide a `placeId` and a `location` for each marker.

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  map: map,
  // Define the place with a location, and a query string.
  place: {
    location: {lat: 44.4948543, lng: -81.3695635},
    placeId: "ChIJydDgDrzPKYgR5ME3zdbglZ8",
  },
  // Attributions help users find your site again.
  attribution: {
    source: 'Google Maps JavaScript API',
    webUrl: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/'
  }
});
var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
  map: map,
  // Define the place with a location, and a query string.
  place: {
    location: {lat: 44.373129, lng: -81.438245},
    placeId: "ChIJaW-levq1KYgR5VDN9cpgH1c",
  },
  // Attributions help users find your site again.
  attribution: {
    source: 'Google Maps JavaScript API',
    webUrl: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/'
  }
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/74zfffj3/4/)

**code snippet** (doesn't seem to work with "signed_in=true"):

```js
function initMap() {
  // When you add a marker using a Place instead of a location, the Maps
  // API will automatically add a 'Save to Google Maps' link to any info
  // window associated with that marker.
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 11,
    center: {
      lat: 44.429734680509064,
      lng: -81.52421951293945
    }
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    // Define the place with a location, and a query string.
    place: {
      location: {
        lat: 44.4948543,
        lng: -81.3695635
      },
      placeId: "ChIJydDgDrzPKYgR5ME3zdbglZ8",
    },
    // Attributions help users find your site again.
    attribution: {
      source: 'Google Maps JavaScript API',
      webUrl: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/'
    }
  });

  var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    // Define the place with a location, and a query string.
    place: {
      location: {
        lat: 44.373129,
        lng: -81.438245
      },
      placeId: "ChIJaW-levq1KYgR5VDN9cpgH1c",
    },
    // Attributions help users find your site again.
    attribution: {
      source: 'Google Maps JavaScript API',
      webUrl: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/'
    }
  });

  // Construct a new InfoWindow.
  var infoWindow1 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: 'Google Sydney'
  });
  var infoWindow2 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: 'Google Sydney'
  });

  // Opens the InfoWindow when marker is clicked.
  marker.addListener('click', function() {
    infoWindow1.setContent("Southampton, CA");
    infoWindow1.open(map, marker);
  });

  marker2.addListener('click', function() {
    infoWindow2.setContent("North Bruce, CA");
    infoWindow2.open(map, marker2);

  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?signed_in=true"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback geocodezip. The reason I don't use `placeId` is because not all `placeId`'s are able to be saved to your google account. For example my markers above have the `placeId`'s marker1: `Eik1NDMgU3Vuc2V0IERyLCBLaW5jYXJkaW5lLCBPTiBOMEgsIENhbmFkYQ` | marker2: `Ei01NiBIYXJtYW4gQXZlLCBTYXVnZWVuIFNob3JlcywgT04gTjBILCBDYW5hZGE` . Using your example these placeId's are not able to be saved. That's why I was trying to use a `query` with a `lat, lng` instead.

Comment: Those two placeIds [work for me (fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/Lvka1kzg/)

Comment: That's strange. When I ran `geocoder()` to find `placeId`'s on my markers found in https://jsfiddle.net/74zfffj3/ .I got the 2 `placeId` mentioned above, but in your fiddle the markers are in different locations when you plot the `placeId`. I would like to save the 2 marker locations found in my fiddle example. Is that possible?

Comment: Don't know, the coordinates in my fiddle are from a lookup of the placeId.

Comment: I see. Do you think there is anyway to get `query` to work for more than 1 marker instead of using `placeId`? Since `placeId` has to be an actual place stored in googles database, I will not get the results I want. Since I am trying to save a lat,lng. If I use `query` and search by a `lat,lng` string it returns the correct locations, but I will only be able to save the first marker. Any markers after that will have a greyed out `Save to Google Maps`.